# NSCalendarUnitEra should i care in general case?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nscalendar

The `NSCalendar` has a unit `NSCalendarUnitEra` which represents B.C. and A.D. which is a higher granularity than Year

However, i noticed, that many libraries and even myself don't care about Era

**So what is the recommendation about dealing with era? is it fine always to use 0? (current era is 1), or should i everywhere correct my code to use the current era? What are the implications of both?**

**From**

```
    NSDateComponents * dc = [NSDateComponents new];
    dc.day = [c[0] integerValue];
    dc.month = [c[1] integerValue];
    dc.year = [c[2] integerValue];
    NSDate * date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dc];
```

**To**

```
    NSDateComponents * dc = [NSDateComponents new];
    dc.era = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitEra fromDate:[NSDate new]];

    dc.day = [c[0] integerValue];
    dc.month = [c[1] integerValue];
    dc.year = [c[2] integerValue];
    NSDate * date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dc];
```

Comment: What does [the documentation of NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents?language=objc) say about unused components?

Comment: What is the era of `date` if you don't set the era component?

Comment: if i don't set it, than it's BC (era 0)... and thats what made me to start thinking about this

Comment: I tried your From code and the era of `date` is 1. How do you get era 0?

Comment: i must have made a mistake... the era is 1, whcicorresponds to the current era... looks like that undefined components NSDateComponentUndefined are assigned the current date value... so since we are in era 1, the result is 1 too... like if you wouldn't specify month, the month would be the current month